# Passing multiple field payload in AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am following the documentation at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/ to setup an API gateway in front of sagemaker-api.

In Section 5 `Step 5: Create a mapping template for request integration` there is a snippet of code that maps `user_id` to the sagemaker api's payload.
The specific snippet of code I am referring to is

```
{
  "instances": [
#set( $user_id = $input.params("user_id") )
#set( $items = $input.params("items") )
#foreach( $item in $items.split(",") )
    {"in0": [$user_id], "in1": [$item]}#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
    $esc.newline
#end
  ]
}
```

I have a multi-field JSON that I want to pass through as-is.
My incoming JSON is of the form:

```
{
  "USER": "HENRY",
  "YR": "2022",
  "CAR":"HONDA",
  "MILES":"2025"
}
```

I will not have multiple entries like in the example. But I need to forward this entire payload to the endpoint. How do I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever application you have that is taking in your input payload, you want to configure that payload in a format that your model will understand. For example the JSON you have you will want to serialize and format properly for ingestion. An example of sending a request to API GW using plain JavaScript:

```
var requestData = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
    console.log(requestData);
    fetch('https://c24ge3u77j.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/helloworld',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify
        ({text: requestData}),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
```

As long as the payload is something your model can infer upon you can simply pass in the JSON as is.